# Perl - Moose::Error::Default missing from latest Moose release

Tags: perl, moose

I have some Perl code using Moose which use a custom error class.
Like this :

```
use metaclass (
    metaclass   => 'Moose::Meta::Class',
    error_class => 'My::Custom::Class',
);
```

Where `My::Custom::Class` is derived from `Moose::Error::Default`.
This used to work fine with Moose 2.0401. I recently upgraded Moose to the latest 2.1603 version and it is not working anymore.
The reason is that it seems that The whole `Moose::Error::*` tree is gone.
I did have a look at the Moose change log but I could not find neither why it was removed nor how I'm supposed to update my code with those packages missing.

Answer (score 5):

The module disappeared in 2.1101. The related [Changes](https://github.com/moose/Moose/blob/e6b297e9247d2e2ea99ebd8fc9761247ba54ab31/Changes#L419) entry says:

> 2.1101   2013-10-20 (TRIAL RELEASE)
>
> [ENHANCEMENTS]
>
> - Moose string exceptions have been replaced by Moose::Exception objects. See
>     Moose::Manual::Delta for details.

Answer (score 2):

`Moose::Error` has never been public API and wasn't intended for use in code outside of Moose. For your own code you should use something like the [Throwable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Throwable) role. If you want to add more structure or create a hierarchy of exception classes you can do it in the ordinary Moose way — use `has` in your exception base class (the one does `with Throwable`) and/or create a bunch of subclasses of it.